# Error: request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm having trouble with my code. My program is a program to simplify fractions. So my problem is this:

I declare the structure Fraction. And then I declare structure Fraction f in my main function.

But when I try to use any member of the structure fraction (i.e. f.num, f.den) it says it's not a member of a structure or union. I have like 10 errors all saying the same thing for my program.

The error (verbatim): error: request for member "num" in something not a structure of union

```
#include <stio.h>

struct Fraction{
    int num;
    int den;
    int lownum;//lownum = lowest numerator.
    int lowden;//lowden = lowest denominator
    int error;
};

void enter(struct Fraction *f);
void simplify(struct Fraction *f);
void display(const struct Fraction *f);


int main(void){
    struct Fraction f;

    printf("Fraction Simplifier\n");
    printf("===================\n");

    enter(&f);
    simplify(&f);
    display(&f);
}

void enter(struct Fraction *f){
    printf("Please enter numerator : \n");
    scanf("%d", &f.num);

    printf("please enter denominator : \n");
    scanf("%d", &f.den);

    printf("%d %d", f.num, f.den);
}

void simplify(struct Fraction *f){
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int negative; //is fraction positive?

    a = f.num;
    b = f.den;

    if (a/b < 0){
        negative = 1;
    }

    if(b == 0){
        f.error = 1;
    }

    if(a < 0){
        a = a * -1;
    }

    if(b < 0){
        b = b * -1;
    }

    //euclids method
    if(a < b){
        c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    while(b != 0){
        c = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    f.lownum = f.num / a;
    f.lowden = f.den / a;

    if(negative = 1){
        f.lownum = f.lownum * -1;
    }
}

void display (const struct Fraction *f){
    if (f.error != 1){
        printf("%d / %d", f.lownum, f.lowden);
    }else{
        printf("error");    
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `<stdio.h>`. Please try and use a better indentation.

Comment: Tip: In C convention, the only non-error errorcode is 0. A function returning both errorcodes and non-errors reserves either 0 (for pointers), all negative values (for functions returning non-negative) or if nothing else is possible one specific return value which is either explicitly not a possible success and/or is supported by errno. For truth values, convention says 0 is false, all else is true.

Answer (score 6):

In

```
void simplify(struct Fraction *f)
```

`f` is a *pointer* to `struct Fraction`. Therefore, instead of

```
a = f.num;
```

you have to write

```
a = (*f).num;
```

which can be shortened to the equivalent notation:

```
a = f->num;
```

The same applies to all other references to `struct Fraction *f` in your functions.

Comment: how can I do this if I have `typedef struct Fraction Fraction` and `Fraction **f`, where `Fraction` is not `typedef` instance. I checked I cant do `**f->num` . It gives same error. Is there any way I can get `struct` back from `typedef` instance in order to access its members?

Answer (score 0):

You use a pointer (struct Fraction *f). So you have to acces members with the -> operator:

```
f->num
```